What is the spectral density matrix, in the context of vector stochastic processes
I cannot seem to find any good/easy to read resources on the spectral theory, and in particular for multivariate stochastic processes.
I want to know:

Any resources explaining spectral theory
Definition of the spectral density matrix
Is the spectral density matrix symmetric?
Relation to the covariance matrix?

